# Partitions Settings in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, dds, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I ported a RWM for RTI Connext Micro DDS. This DDS does not support partitions. However ROS2 uses partitions for the topics (rt) and other messages in the RMW.
https://github.com/ros2/design/blob/gh-pages/articles/140_topic_and_service_name_mapping.md

Is it possible to disable the creation of DDS partitions in ROS2?

Thanks :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282152/partitions-settings-in-ros2/) by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 527 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment you can't disable the usage of partitions. But based on recent discussions we will likely soon modify all RMW implementation to switch from using partitions to only topic names. An upcoming DDS spec will allow forward slashes in the topic name and we will start using that (all vendors except OpenSplice already support that). There will be more information about why this is being changed.

It would be great if you could share information about your work. I know at least two groups which are working on / having a Connext micro based RMW impl. It would be really good to merge these efforts rather than duplicate the work.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-02-08**:
Thanks for your answer. I am waiting forward for this update :D

I cannot share the code (yet) but I will upstream the implementation of the RMW soon. I also had to modify some of the code inside Connext Micro.
Apart from the services and partitions I think everything is implemented.